# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "module"

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, angular-cli, nginx-reverse-proxy

i ve and angular app which i run under nginx

my index.html of my app lokks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <title>My app</title>
  <base href=".">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favico.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" type="text/html" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.b42090261d222dbcaff0.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.0dae8cbc97194c7caed4.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.0dae8cbc97194c7caed4.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.881a5e902dad2fa1b521.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.4105ab30eb3bb82ec839.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="scripts.ab9a830162507381a850.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor-es2015.4ae0fe134a343ec76cbe.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="vendor-es5.4ae0fe134a343ec76cbe.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="main-es2015.84f12989afdbfdeb0459.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.84f12989afdbfdeb0459.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

When running in browser i'm getting this error

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "module". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec
```

Saying that it can't recognize the ecmascript modules files

Under my nginx.conf i ve tried to add the "module" type to MIMES types of nginx like this :

```
http {
   include mime.types;
   types {
      module js;
   }
   default_type application/octet-stream;
```

But the problem persists , remember that my app need to be run on **es2015** and not **es5**

**Is there any way to fix this problem ?**

Comment: Your statement `types { module js; }` tells Nginx that **all** `.js` files are MIME type "module" - remove it. Otherwise, I do not understand where the word "module" is being generated by Nginx. You will need to identify the full URL of the source file that's causing the problem and look at the headers using `curl -I`

Comment: @RichardSmith ok seems like the problem appears somtimes ,when inigtially loading the application , and i ve doubted , that nginx doesn t tell that files of types="module" are js , that's why i ve tried to force it..

Comment: @RichardSmith : <script src="polyfills-es2015.4105ab30eb3bb82ec839.js" type="module"></script>
 do this tell that it's aleardy a file of type "application/javasctipt" ?

Comment: Nginx only sees the `polyfills-es2015.4105ab30eb3bb82ec839.js` part, which ends with `.js` so should match the appropriate MIME type in the `mime.types` file. You should test the server using `curl -I https://example.com/polyfills-es2015.4105ab30eb3bb82ec839.js` and see what it sends back.

Comment: @RichardSmith ok i tested it with fiddler , and that seems to send the right file (that doesn fail to download the file), but that would be blocked sometimes in the browser saying the error "file blocked due to wrong file MIME type"

Comment: @RichardSmith ok after i removed my wrong types {..} , i got this error : Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Comment: @RichardSmith seems like that didn t recognize perfectly the type of thos js file , and get get confused to see them like html ??

Comment: The "text/html" error is usually because the file was not found on the server and so the default action is to send `index.html` instead. Check that the file is present, readable, and in the correct location relative to document root.

Comment: @RichardSmith the problem that it doesn't happen always , but only sometimes , so if there were such a problem of the file presence or path , that wouldn t work ,,, that seems to confuse me more , also using fiddler  i ve got code 200 when downloading the files

Comment: You are using a relative URI in your `src=` statements, so the browser will use the current pages URL to make it absolute. You can check this using the Nginx access log to see what the actual URI is.

Comment: under access.log ; i ve had almost 200 and 304 https resultst , that mean that it would well loaded , thar looks like this : 10.197.121.142 - - [28/Apr/2021:12:44:51 +0200] "GET /root/polyfills-es2015.4105ab30eb3bb82ec839.js HTTP/1.1" 200 247060 0.000